# Incoming call broadcast receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener, incoming-call

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm unable to catch incoming calls using broadcast receiver. I've double and triple checked my manifest file for necessary permissions. Everything seems okay but don't know why, the receiver is not working. Can anybody please suggest the reason for this? Any help would be appreciated!
Here is my skeleton code:

Main:

```
package com.calllistener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);       
    }
}
```

`MyPhoneStateListener` Class:

```
package com.calllistener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context ctx;
    public MyPhoneStateListener (Context ctx) {
        super();
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.calllistener"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Call listener" >
        <receiver android:name="MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: asked many times here ... at least one activity should be run first ...

Comment: I've seen most of the solutions, and none of them is working in my case. By the way, why do you say the activity is necessary to run the code? The receiver won't wake up during incoming call event?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: Use this answer and try it again https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159603/5359340 . i hope this will work. if you found any answers please  post your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use should use `registerReceiver(Receiver, Filter);` in your activity as Selvin said to init your BroadCastReceiver and that's all there's to it.

Comment: Or in the manifest, add the android:enabled="true" to the receiver